# Alcatraz plugin isn't installing?

Tags: xcode5, alcatraz

According to this github entry https://github.com/chendo/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin, I should be able to install FuzzyAutocompletePlugin into XCode 5 using Alcatraz.

When I try to follow the very simple terminal instructions for installing Alcatraz posted at the github entry https://github.com/mneorr/alcatraz, I don't see a plugin manager in my Window menu of XCode after restarting it. No errors were shown in the terminal, however I did see 2 lines that looked like download lines. The first one went to 100%, the other 0%.

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins;
curl -L http://goo.gl/xfmmt | tar xv -C ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins -
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   237    0   237    0     0   1126      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2788
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0x Alcatraz.xcplugin/
```

So I tried downloading the repository to rebuild it, however I can't build it because I get errors. The workspace has a missing project (Pods.xcodeproj). The project has entries for files that aren't there either.

I would love to try out Alcatraz, however I find myself stuck. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed now. You can download Alcatraz 1.0 from http://alcatraz.io

Answer (score 4):

I’m sorry Aaron, but this is a known bug in the prebuilt version of Alcatraz. This has been fixed in [74edeba134c1](https://github.com/mneorr/Alcatraz/commit/74edeba134c124163802d494ab3cca764f912edf); unfortunately, the developers have yet to update the prebuilt version of Alcatraz. I’ve filed a bug with them on GitHub because of this.

Until then, I’m afraid you’ll have to build Alcatraz from source. The missing `Pods.xcodeproj` file you mentioned is actually generated by a program called [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org). Follow the directions on their website to install it (I had to build another copy of Ruby to get it to work; I used [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).) Once CocoaPods is installed, open a Terminal to the directory containing the `Podfile` file and run the command `pod install`. Once that command completes successfully, you will be able to successfully open and build Alcatraz.

Comment: Still not working with the prebuilt version as of Nov 10th. Hope they fix it soon.